# C# - Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfArray' no tipo 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de assinatura digital com certificados `A1` e `A3 (token)` para `pdfs` juntamente com `iTextsharp (v5.5.13.1, via NuGet Package Manager)`. Utilizo o `c#` e me deparei com o seguinte erro ao criar um objeto `PdfReader`:

> $exception {"Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfArray' no tipo 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary'."} System.InvalidCastException

O arquivo em questão é um `pdf` digitalizado, com as demais formas, de nada ocorre, funciona normalmente.

Faço a leitura de todos os `pdfs` a partir de um diretório conforme abaixo, e prossigo com um `foreach` no `array`:

```
pgbAssinaturas.Maximum = aArquivos.Length;

string[] aArquivos = Directory.GetFiles(txbPathPdfs2.Text, "*.pdf");
foreach (string sArquivo in aArquivos) {

   // atualiza progressbar
   iContadorProgressBar++;
   pgbAssinaturas.Value = iContadorProgressBar;
   pgbAssinaturas.Refresh();
   
   // abre arquivo original
   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sArquivo); // <-- linha do erro

   // prepara um nome final
   sNomeArquivoFinal = "Assinados\\sign_" + Path.GetFileName(sArquivo);
   sNomeArquivoFinal = txbPathPdfs2.Text + "\\" + sNomeArquivoFinal;

   // [...]
}
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar ocorrendo com esse pdf de fato?

IDE: `visual studio community 2019, .Net Framework 4.8.03752`

Comment: em qual trecho do código o erro acontece?

Comment: `PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sArquivo);`. Editei o post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era o `pdf` mesmo. Por algum motivo quando salvei pela primeira vez, acabou se corrompendo.

Porém, criei um código para validar os problemas, o bom e velho `try{ }catch(Exception ex){ }`

```
try {
   // abre arquivo original
   // tenta criar
   PdfReader pdfReaderTest = new PdfReader(sArquivo);
   pdfReaderTest.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   // se for um pdf inválido, informa
   MessageBox.Show("erro: " + ex.Message)
   continue;
}
```